# Gunicorn shows 404 instead of app

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask app that I am trying to run through Gunicorn.

The app is located in a module, lets say its called "mymodule", and the `__init__.py` file located in `mymodule/` looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

However, no matter the URL, a 404 error is returned.

I have tried running Gunicorn in the folder that contains the mymodule folder:

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:5000 mymodule:app
```

I have tried pointing Gunicorn at my debug file, "runapp.py" in the root, by running `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:5000 runapp.py`, but that results in `error: [Errno 48] Address already in use`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: File structure

```
/runapp.py
/mymodule/__init__.py
/mymodule/views.py
```

**runapp.py:**

```
from mymodule import app, views
app.run(debug=True)
```

**`__init.py__`**:

```
from flask import Flask
from mymodule import views

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**views.py**:

```
from mymodule import api
from mymodule.forms import SettingsForm
from functools import wraps
from flask import request, Response, render_template, redirect, url_for

[...]

@app.route('/')
@requires_auth
def dashboard():
    data = api.get_overview()
    return render_template('dashboard.html', data=data)
```

Comment: You application doesn't handle any path. Shouldn't you at least handle the path "/"?

Comment: That code is located in another part of the application - there is a route that handles / - and it works fine if I just run "python runapp.py" without Gunicorn.

Comment: But you are using `gunicorn mymodule:app`, so `app` is used, not `runapp`.

Comment: Yes - ok that might be an issue. It seems that the `__init__.py` file doesn't import `app`. If I say that it should `from mymodule import app`, it says that `ImportError: cannot import name app`. Only happens when loading directly through Gunicorn - if I do `python runapp.py` it works fine.

Comment: My problem is that you keep mentioning `runapp.py`, but you've only shown us `__init__.py`, so it's not easy to guess... What does `runapp.py` expose?

Comment: Edited the question with some more code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get `Errno 48` because the same port (`5000`) is already busy for another application, which means you run your app twice, probably.

The `404` issue is caused by the lack of routes. The routes aren't properly attached to `app` because you don't import it in your `views` module. From [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/):

> Here’s an example `__init__.py`:
>
> ```
> from flask import Flask
> app = Flask(__name__)
>
> import yourapplication.views
> ```
>
> And this is what views.py would look like:
>
> ```
> from yourapplication import app
>
> @app.route('/')
> def index():
>     return 'Hello World!'
> ```

Notice that in `__init__.py` views are imported **after** creating the Flask instance.

Comment: I don't get it. I have defined routes (also "/") in views.py in my mymodule folder. Works fine when I run the app through runapp.py.

Comment: Done - it's in the original question.

Comment: @phidah I've edited my answer, check to see if it helps, please.